# How to check class name exists in css file?

Tags: css

I will run a foreach in html.

I am using .net mvc c#.

How can i check the classname if it exists in my stylesheet css file?

`foreach(var item in list) 
{ <div class="@item.classname">@item.classname</div>}`

Comment: There is no "foreach" in html.

Comment: Looks like e's using a template system (curly brackets).  Regardless, if the style isn't present in the CSS, nothing will happen.

Comment: Hi, why would you need to do this test, I had never have to do such a test :O

Comment: Hi,because that class is my icon logo(font file).so i need to check it,when not exists in my css file, i need to set to default icon.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if a class exists by using the JavaScript `classList` property.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.hello');

console.log(div.classList.contains('hello'));
console.log(div.classList.contains('world'));
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
```